# Is ETW available in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-event-log, eventviewer

We have an application that is writing to ETW (event tracing for windows) using an `ETWTrackingParticipant` for trace output. Does anyone know if ETW is supported in Windows Server 2003 or if it only exists in Windows Server 2008? If so - how do we get to the same ETW view we have in Windows Server 2008 (**Event Viewer->Application and Services Logs->Microsoft->Windows->Application-Server Applications->Analytic**)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes ETW is available.

But there is no UI that supports showing ETW logs – you will need to write your own.